# php - Sum array value per day in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

There are a number of great Q&As on Stackoverflow on how to sum across a multidimensional associative array but I have not found a working example of doing subtotals within a multidimensional one.

For instance I have data coming out of a mysql query into php with this shape:

```
$myArray = array(
    '2014-4-3' => 2,
    '2014-4-4' => 3,
    '2014-4-5' => array(
        0 => 3,
        1 => 7,
        2 => 7,
        3 => 7
    )
);
```

Essentially, I am pulling the ratings made of restaurants by day. Some days might have many ratings and others will have fewer (those days with no ratings are omitted from the array). On days with more ratings I would like to sum up to a total for that given day so a new array would look simply as follows:

```
'2014-4-3' => 2
'2014-4-4' => 3
'2014-4-5' => 24
```

I have tried for hours to hack the foreach and functions approaches posted for summing multidimensional arrays but nothing so far. One key problem is that the days themselves aren't known in advance as each day is added the same process must be expanded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_sum()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php):

```
$output = array_map(function($a) { 
    return is_array($a) ? array_sum($a) : $a; 
}, $myArray);
```

#### [Here's a demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/J2L4Jb)

Comment: Amazing! This is an elegant solution but I will have to do a bunch of reading to work out how it actually works ;-) Tx.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use nested `foreach` with `is_array()`

```
$myArray = array(
    '2014-4-3' => 2,
    '2014-4-4' => 3,
    '2014-4-5' => array(
        0 => 3,
        1 => 7,
        2 => 7,
        3 => 7
    )
);
$new=array();
foreach($myArray as $day=>$value){
    $newval =0;
    if(is_array($value)){
        foreach ($value as $val) {
            $newval += $val;
        }
    }else{
        $newval = $value;
    }
    $new[$day]=$newval;
}

var_dump($new);
```

Comment: This is a great way to solve the issue. I'll probably also use this approach in my next step as it very clear what is being done through the iterations and will be quite adaptable to adding in extra features.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
foreach($myArray as &$value){
    if(is_array($value)){
         $value = array_sum($value);
    }
}
```